# Можно ли получить посты чужой группы facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Можно ли получить посты чужой группы facebook? Возможно ли через API это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Не в курсе по поводу API но можно написать простой парсер на Python если уж очень туго с API и не будет других вариантов. Есть множество библиотек для этого, да и знаний Python`а там особо много не нужно. Лично я использовал библиотеку "Beautiful soup 4", она достаточно популярная. Можешь в ТГ написать если будут вопросы @GachiLetherMan. Посмотрев видосик на ютубе на тему парсера сайтов можно разобраться. Можно получить текст, фото да и всё вообще, что видит пользователь на сайте. Это по сути парсинг html кода.

Comment: это скорее комментарий, чем ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin для коментария у него рейтинг не вырос еще :)